# Methods as values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to execute methods through a scheme like below. There would be 10 or so method. Two questions:
Is there an option to make it work as below or similarly?
Would putting 10 if/elif statements for each key be a grief on good programming practice?

Code below just prints 
test n1
test n2
and I'd want it to print only 'test n2'
Thanks

```
def testmethod(v):
    a='test n%i'%v
    print(a)

dictionary = {'aaa':testmethod(1), 'bbb':testmethod(2)}
a=dictionary['bbb']
```

Comment: Elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: well the reason it prints both `test n1` and `test n2` is because in the dictionary is not the function stored, but what the function returns. Therefore the function is called. If you remove `a=dictionary['bbb']` you will get the same result and if you check `a` it will be `None`.

Comment: I don't see any problem by populating values of dict using function

Comment: yup, just understood it. Thank you!

Comment: it may seem quite unclear why I'd want to do that: I get two variables, one with known name of a method(eg aaa ) and a value that i need to apply as an argument to the aaa method.

Comment: @Clément it is not a problem to populate a dictionary via callables, but here the callables return `None` and that is pretty sure not what @killerwhale intended to do.

Comment: @killerwhale well in that case you would have to save your callables as callables in your dictionary. 
my_dict={'func1':testmethod}
Which then you can call via my_dict['func1'](1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's incorrect syntax as you are currently putting **result** of invoked function in your dictionary, while you want callable:

```
dictionary = {'aaa':testmethod, 'bbb':testmethod}
a=dictionary['bbb'](2)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That way you could just call `testmethod(2)`. That is just basically renaming the function.

Comment: understandable enough - got what I needed